# Cannot properly use the Makefile for some course files

Tags: c++

I am trying to work through the following http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~keenan/Projects/DGPDEC/paper.pdf. The following source files are used to illustrate what is going on https://github.com/dgpdec/course. Now I cannot get it to work. Here is what I tried:

First I went into the folder 'basecode', edited the Makefile to have the right include and library paths. Then I want to make but it gives me the error

'ostream’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type

I looked for this error online but I could not find a solution to the problem. In the included file libddg_userguide.pdf  it says that I should edit the Makefile in root libddg folder but I don't know which folder that is. I am sorry for the kind of nooby question but I am really stuck and have been trying for a long time. Here is the Makefile I used (in the Basecode folder) for reference:

```
##########################################################################################

# Specify library locations here (add or remove "#" marks to comment/uncomment lines for your platform)

# Linux
DDG_INCLUDE_PATH      = -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/suitesparse
DDG_LIBRARY_PATH      = -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib 
DDG_BLAS_LIBS         = -llapack -lblas -lgfortran
DDG_SUITESPARSE_LIBS  = -lspqr -lcholmod -lmetis -lcolamd -lccolamd -lcamd -lamd -lm
DDG_OPENGL_LIBS       = -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11

########################################################################################

TARGET = ddg
CC = g++
LD = g++
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic  $(DDG_INCLUDE_PATH) -I./include -I./src
LFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic $(DDG_LIBRARY_PATH)
LIBS = $(DDG_OPENGL_LIBS) $(DDG_SUITESPARSE_LIBS) $(DDG_BLAS_LIBS)

########################################################################################
## !! Do not edit below this line

HEADERS := $(wildcard include/*.h)
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)))

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET) $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp ${HEADERS}
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    rm -f $(TARGET).exe
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means **there is a bug in the code**: a header's missing because [someone made an assumption](http://kera.name/articles/2010/08/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-6-an-inclusion-pitfall/).

Your particular toolchain does not satisfy that assumption.

Find the problematic file (you didn't say which it is) and add `#include <ostream>` to it.

*(`course/Connection/include/DenseMatrix.h` appears to be one such file; there may be others.)*

N.B. I must say that, despite the bug, overall this is incredibly good C++ code for a University course. I'm impressed.

Comment: Yeah sorry I added it to the densematric.cpp file instead of the densematrix.h file. It now works but at some point gives the same error for a different file (sparsematrix). Should I update all the files individually or is there a way to do it in one go? Thanks a lot for the helpful answer

Comment: @Slugger: Yes just go through them one error at a time. You're probably really close to a good build. You could consider submitting the fixes to the Git repo when you're done (and link back here for context if you like).